# Adding a user-defined prefix for a column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, check-constraints

In my `patient` table, I want all the patient IDs to start with the `'PT'` prefix. For example, `PT01`, `PT02`, ...

My code is:

```
CREATE TABLE patient
(
     p_id varchar(10) PRIMARY KEY CHECK(p_id in('PT%')),
     pname varchar(22)
)
```

It does not work... any suggestions?

Comment: This is a secondary business-/client-side numbering. Which may be altered. This may be unique but you don't have to make it PK. Use surrogate `int identity` field - this will avoid a plenty of troubles with your magic STRING-NUMBERS.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `like`

```
CREATE TABLE PATIENT
(
  P_ID  VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY CHECK(P_ID  LIKE'PT%' ),
  PNAME VARCHAR(22)
)
```